# How can i call function with default and optional parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript

My function

```
   inputMinMaxValidation(name: string, max: any = 100, i?: number): void {
          ...........
          ...........
          ...........
    }
```

In this function I've to call last optional parameter (**i**). My call `inputMinMaxValidation('Hello', 100 , 1)` . **But I don't want  reassign my default value.**

I tried

```
inputMinMaxValidation('Hello', false , 1)

inputMinMaxValidation('Hello', null , 1)
```

But It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters), use undefined:

As given example :

```
function buildName(firstName: string, lastName = "Smith") {
return firstName + " " + lastName;
```

}

let result2 = buildName("Bob", undefined);

Comment: Sure But I want to wait a little more.